# Count the number of a string appearance between two patterns

Tags: regex, awk, sed

For text file like this:

```
START_PATTERN

...TAG1...
...TAG2...
...TAG3...
...TAG4...
STOP_PATTERN

START_PATTERN
...TAG1...
...TAG5...
...TAG4...
...TAG1...
STOP_PATTERN
```

I want to return the first block(between start and end) having at least 2 TAG1 and 4 total lines.
So the result in this case would simply be:

```
START_PATTERN
...TAG1...
...TAG5...
...TAG4...
...TAG1...
STOP_PATTERN
```

I have tried this:

```
   awk 'x {next}
      /START_PATTERN/
      {n=1;f=1;count=0}f {lines[n++]=$0}  
      /END_PATTERN/
      {if(n==4){/TAG1/count++;x=1}}  #the message should appear for 9 lines
      {print count}' file
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `awk` script:

```
/START/{
    p=1; tag=0; tot=0;
    lines = "";
}
p{
    if ($0 ~ /TAG/)
        tot++;
    if ($0 ~ /TAG1/)
        tag++;
    lines = lines RS $0
}
/STOP/{
    p=0;
    if (tot == 4 && tag>=2)
        print lines;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another working `awk`:

```
awk '/START_PATTERN/ {
   p=$0
   lines=1
   next
}
p != "" {
   p = p ORS $0
   lines++
}
/STOP_PATTERN/ && split(p,a,"TAG1")>2 && lines>=4 {
   print p
}' file

START_PATTERN
...TAG1...
...TAG5...
...TAG4...
...TAG1...
STOP_PATTERN
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/START/{:a;N;/STOP/!ba;/(TAG1).*\1/!b;/([^\n]*TAG[^\n]*\n){4,}/!b;p;q}' file
```

Turn on seds grep-like nature and collect lines between `START` and `STOP`. If those lines collected contain two or more `TAG1`'s and four or more `TAG` lines print and then abort.